# imagestring can not write barcode string

Tags: php, barcode

I have a barcode generator PHP code. It works very fine and shows barcode in browser. But when I want to convert it to PNG by `imagestring` , the image does not contain the barcode ! Also I used `echo gettype($i)` to know what is the type of string variable and that showed it is STRING. The barcode generator that I use is below.

```
<style>
div.b128{
 border-left: 1px black solid;
 height: 30px;
} 
</style>
<?php
global $char128asc,$char128charWidth;
$char128asc=' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'; 
$char128wid = array(
 '212222','222122','222221','121223','121322','131222','122213','122312','132212','221213', // 0-9 
 '221312','231212','112232','122132','122231','113222','123122','123221','223211','221132', // 10-19 
 '221231','213212','223112','312131','311222','321122','321221','312212','322112','322211', // 20-29 
 '212123','212321','232121','111323','131123','131321','112313','132113','132311','211313', // 30-39 
 '231113','231311','112133','112331','132131','113123','113321','133121','313121','211331', // 40-49 
 '231131','213113','213311','213131','311123','311321','331121','312113','312311','332111', // 50-59 
 '314111','221411','431111','111224','111422','121124','121421','141122','141221','112214', // 60-69 
 '112412','122114','122411','142112','142211','241211','221114','413111','241112','134111', // 70-79 
 '111242','121142','121241','114212','124112','124211','411212','421112','421211','212141', // 80-89 
 '214121','412121','111143','111341','131141','114113','114311','411113','411311','113141', // 90-99
 '114131','311141','411131','211412','211214','211232','23311120' ); // 100-106

////Define Function
function bar128($text) { // Part 1, make list of widths
 global $char128asc,$char128wid; 
 $w = $char128wid[$sum = 104]; // START symbol
 $onChar=1;
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($text);$x++) // GO THRU TEXT GET LETTERS
 if (!( ($pos = strpos($char128asc,$text[$x])) === false )){ // SKIP NOT FOUND CHARS
 $w.= $char128wid[$pos];
 $sum += $onChar++ * $pos;
 } 
 $w.= $char128wid[ $sum % 103 ].$char128wid[106]; //Check Code, then END
 //Part 2, Write rows
 $html="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>"; 
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($w);$x+=2) // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
 $html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div></td>"; 
 return "<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=2>$text</td></tr></table>$html<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=2>$text</td></tr></table>"; 
}
?>
```

And I use code below to generate barcode and convert to PNG:

```
<?php

    $code='ab1234cd';
    include 'barcode128.php';
    $bar_code=bar128($code);

$font  = 20;
$text=$bar_code;
$width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($text);
$height = imagefontheight($font);

// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate($width, $height);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, $font, 0, 0, $text, $textcolor);

// Output the image
#header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im, 'f.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I think the problem is with the string that is made by barcode-generator because PNG file contains the last line of barcode-generator code!!! Look at picture attached.
[image]

[image: zood on firsed pic]

As you can see it is the last line of barcode-generator after `return`

Comment: You can not write HTML code onto an image, and expect that to get _interpreted_ as such.

Comment: @CBroe I can not understand what HTML code you meant. When I `echo` the string `$text` it is clearly shown and is a string. Can you please explain more? Also I used `strval($bar_code);` to change any kind of variable to string but the result is same

Comment: Well the HTML code that your function returns, `return "<tr><td colspan="...` _"When I echo the string $text it is clearly shown and is a string."_ - because then your browser, which was _expecting_ HTML to begin with, _interprets_ that HTML code. But that doesn't mean that your string did not contain HTML tags, you just don't get to _see them_ in that context.

Comment: @CBroe I am a little understood, so what is the solution to solve this with my codes that I have?

Comment: I tried to use
`ob_start();  
echo $bar_code; 
$content = ob_get_clean(); `
but it did not work too.

Comment: Using the output buffer doesn't change the fact that you don't have any image data, but only HTML. You would have to re-write the whole barcode generation part, so that it sets pixels or draws little rectangles onto an image, instead of creating an HTML table with borders for the bars.

Comment: @CBroe how about making a string instead of "sets pIixels or draws little rectangles onto an image" ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If its only about generating barcodes and saving the generated images then why don't you try [this](https://github.com/anigenero/php-barcode-generator)?

The example is very self explanatory, the code is open source so it will welcome your own customizations . :D

```
<?php
    include('../src/Code128Barcode.php');
    ob_start();
    imagepng(Code128Barcode::generate('some text'));
    $img = base64_encode(ob_get_clean());    
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $img . '" />'; //render barcode image in page
    file_put_contents('barcode.png', base64_decode($img)); //save barcode as image file
?>
```

After performing many experiments with your code, I concluded following results

1. You can convert the barcode to image in server side using pure PHP
   using tools e.g. `wkhtmltoimage` example is following

   ```
   wkhtmltoimage http://localhost/barcode.php?q=my%20text test.png
   ```
2. You can convert your barcode to image in client side using
   JavaScript and some other canvas processing tools I modified your
   code a bit and converted your barcode to PNG image using html canvas
   and html to canvas rendering library available [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/#/documentation.html).

The modified code is below

**barcode.php**

Only small change in this file removed the style tag from here and added it to the index (consumer file) listed next to it

```
<?php
global $char128asc,$char128charWidth;
$char128asc=' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'; 
$char128wid = array(
 '212222','222122','222221','121223','121322','131222','122213','122312','132212','221213', // 0-9 
 '221312','231212','112232','122132','122231','113222','123122','123221','223211','221132', // 10-19 
 '221231','213212','223112','312131','311222','321122','321221','312212','322112','322211', // 20-29 
 '212123','212321','232121','111323','131123','131321','112313','132113','132311','211313', // 30-39 
 '231113','231311','112133','112331','132131','113123','113321','133121','313121','211331', // 40-49 
 '231131','213113','213311','213131','311123','311321','331121','312113','312311','332111', // 50-59 
 '314111','221411','431111','111224','111422','121124','121421','141122','141221','112214', // 60-69 
 '112412','122114','122411','142112','142211','241211','221114','413111','241112','134111', // 70-79 
 '111242','121142','121241','114212','124112','124211','411212','421112','421211','212141', // 80-89 
 '214121','412121','111143','111341','131141','114113','114311','411113','411311','113141', // 90-99
 '114131','311141','411131','211412','211214','211232','23311120' ); // 100-106

////Define Function
function bar128($text) { // Part 1, make list of widths
 global $char128asc,$char128wid; 
 $w = $char128wid[$sum = 104]; // START symbol
 $onChar=1;
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($text);$x++) // GO THRU TEXT GET LETTERS
 if (!( ($pos = strpos($char128asc,$text[$x])) === false )){ // SKIP NOT FOUND CHARS
 $w.= $char128wid[$pos];
 $sum += $onChar++ * $pos;
 } 
 $w.= $char128wid[ $sum % 103 ].$char128wid[106]; //Check Code, then END
 //Part 2, Write rows
 $html="<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr>"; 
 for($x=0;$x<strlen($w);$x+=2) // code 128 widths: black border, then white space
 $html .= "<td><div class=\"b128\" style=\"border-left-width:{$w[$x]};width:{$w[$x+1]}\"></div></td>"; 
 return "<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=2>$text</td></tr></table>$html<tr><td colspan=".strlen($w)." align=center><font family=arial size=2>$text</td></tr></table>"; 
}
?>
```

**index.php**

The consumer file, i added some html and javascript to make it work

```
<?php include('barcode.php'); ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Barcode Test</title>
    <style>
        div.b128{
            border-left: 1px black solid;
            height: 30px;
        } 
    </style>
    <script src="./htmltocanvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="#">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Update Text">
<input onclick="SaveImage()" type="button" value="Save Image">
</form>
<label>Actual Barcode Rendered</label>
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px;">
    <?php echo bar128($_GET['q']); ?>
</div>

<script>
function SaveImage()
{
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
        var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
        newlabel.innerHTML = "Barcode after Converting to Image";
        document.body.appendChild(newlabel);
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Output is following, once the canvas is appended to html you can easily download, process or send png image from canvas to server.

[image: output image]

Comment: Thank you @Zain this is a good suggestion but I really want to solve this problem and learn. :)

Comment: @SaeedEisakhani check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you @Zain I prefer not to use libs because when I move my code to another server I have serious problems. Is there any way to save `echo` output to a variable? Or any other way to just convert my barcode, that is printed in browser page, to a recognizable variable!!!

Comment: you can't because your barcode is not being generated as image, the function is generating a html code which is pretending to be image, you have to find a way to convert the rendering of your html code to image, which is not possible without any library however i am still experimenting with pure js or php code

Comment: How about changing barcode generator not to generate barcode as HTML code?

Comment: yeah this is good idea . my first solution is actually based on this . and on moving it wont mess because there is no external library